# How to change image url dynamically in lightGallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightgallery

i have a problem my images are not changing for each `click` of different **images**

**Problem:**

1. on changing different **images** it is not changing
2. preview **image** is always is showing the same image

**Question:**  i want to change image preview for each image

**Demo here:** https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/OrWaRz

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dynamic li').on('click', function(e) {
     var imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('data-src');
     $('.image-wrapper img').attr('src',imgUrl);
  });
  $('.image-wrapper').on('click',function(){
     var imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
      $(this).lightGallery({
          dynamic: true,
          dynamicEl: [{
              src: imgUrl,
              thumb: imgUrl
          }]
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<span>Change images:</span>
<ul id="dynamic">
  <li>images  1<img src="" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/" alt=""></li>
  <li>images  2<img src="" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/" alt=""></li>
  <li>images  3<img src="" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net" alt=""></li>
</ul>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <span style="color:#fff;">click to preview image</span>
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the documentation, it says that you have to [destroy()](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#methods) the current gallery and create it again if you want to refresh the content, reference to the previous indications is [here](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/530). Even doing this, the library still presents some issues, so I manage to get it work adding a delay of `250ms` between the destroy of the previous gallery and the creation of the new one.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#dynamic li').on('click', function(e)
    {
        var imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('data-src');
        $('.image-wrapper img').attr('src', imgUrl);
    });

    $('.image-wrapper').on('click', function()
    {
        var imgUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

        // Destroy previous gallery.
        
        if ($(this).data('lightGallery'))
            $(this).data('lightGallery').destroy(true);

        // Wait some time before create the new gallery.
 
        var target = $(this);

        setTimeout(function()
        {
            target.lightGallery({
                dynamic: true,
                dynamicEl: [{src: imgUrl, thumb: imgUrl}]
            });
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>

<span>Change images:</span>
<ul id="dynamic">
  <li>images  1<img src="" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/" alt=""></li>
  <li>images  2<img src="" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF?Text=Down.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/" alt=""></li>
  <li>images  3<img src="" data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF/?text=IPaddress.net" alt=""></li>
</ul>

<div class="image-wrapper">
  <span style="color:#fff;">click to preview image</span>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com%20C/O%20https://placeholder.com/">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice Answer, but every **Download** is failing can you see that

Comment: Do you mean the `download` button? If yea, that may be because of the security implemented on this site. I tested this same code on your `Codepen` and the download button works...

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, it is **downloading** but downloading a previous image.  can you please verify that

Comment: @skBangalore check next [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPJKYR) of this same code. I'm using **Chrome browser** and the download button works without issues there.